# ls -l in Docker shows question marks in place of file permissions and stats

Tags: docker, glibc, gnu-coreutils, seccomp

Before I begin, there are other questions that mention that `ls -l` produces questions marks but those are due to permissions issue. This question is different. Hopefully!

I have a decommissioned Docker host:

- Kernel 3.10
- docker 18.06
- glibc 2.17
- libseccomp 2.3.1
- coreutils 8.22

I have a SLES 15 docker image

- glibc 2.31
- coreutils 8.32

I start the container using `docker run -it --rm -u root <docker-image> bash`

The home directory I land in has a `bin` directory which I can see using `ls` but if I use `ls -l` I get a lot of question marks.

```bash
$ ls
bin
$ ls -l
ls: cannot access 'bin': Operation not permitted
total 0
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? bin
```

From my research, `ls` in coreutils 8.32 onwards uses `statx` syscall. `statx` was added to Linux in kernel 4.11; library support was added in glibc 2.28. I thought this explains the output of the `ls -l` command - Docker uses the host's kernel and the host's kernel is 3.10 which doesn't have `statx` implemented.

When I start the Docker container without any seccomp profile, `ls -l` works fine!

`docker run -it --rm --security-opt seccomp=unconfined -u root <docker-image> bash`

```bash
$ ls
bin
$ ls -l
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 abcuser abcuser 6 Jul  4  2022 bin
```

Now it appears that this is not really the kernel nor the `statx` support but this is due to the seccomp profile. However, `statx` was [whitelisted in Docker 18.04](https://github.com/moby/moby/commit/b2a907c8cab64830c9e424eb1ec71e0429d326ff) and the host in my example is running 18.06.

I did read a commit message somewhere (forgot to save the link) that said the `ls` implementation defaults to `stat` if `statx` is not available. If so, `ls -l` should have worked with the default seccomp profile.

Can anyone explain why `ls -l` doesn't work with the default seccomp profile? Also, can anyone explain how `ls -l` works without a seccomp profile when the underlying kernel doesn't have `statx` implemented?

I do have `strace` captured. Parts that are of interest is below.

Strace with the default seccomp profile:

```
statx(AT_FDCWD, "bin", AT_STATX_SYNC_AS_STAT|AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW, STATX_MODE|STATX_NLINK|STATX_UID|STATX_GID|STATX_MTIME|STATX_SIZE, 0x7ffcb567a4f0) = -1 ENOSYS (Function not implemented)                                                                                                                                                                                                   
ls: write(2, "ls: ", 4)                     = -1 ENOSYS (Function not implemented)                                                                                                             
cannot access 'bin'write(2, "cannot access 'bin'", 19)     = -1 ENOSYS (Function not implemented)                                                                                              
: Operation not permittedwrite(2, ": Operation not permitted", 25) = -1 ENOSYS (Function not implemented)

write(2, "\n", 1)                       = -1 ENOSYS (Function not implemented)
getdents64(3, 0x560b1d8ff920, 32768)    = -1 ENOSYS (Function not implemented)
close(3)                                = -1 ENOSYS (Function not implemented)
fstat(1, 0x7ffcb567a890)                = -1 ENOSYS (Function not implemented)
total 0
write(1, "total 0\n", 8)                = -1 ENOSYS (Function not implemented)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/localtime", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOSYS (Function not implemented)
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? bin
write(1, "d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? "..., 36) = -1 ENOSYS (Function not implemented)
close(1)                                = -1 ENOSYS (Function not implemented)
close(2)                                = -1 ENOSYS (Function not implemented)
```

Strace without any seccomp profile:

```
statx(AT_FDCWD, "bin", AT_STATX_SYNC_AS_STAT|AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW, STATX_MODE|STATX_NLINK|STATX_UID|STATX_GID|STATX_MTIME|STATX_SIZE, 0x7ffec5a21b10) = -1 ENOSYS (Function not implemented)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "bin", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=6, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
lgetxattr("bin", "security.selinux", 0x55d9b494d930, 255) = -1 ENODATA (No data available)
getxattr("bin", "system.posix_acl_access", NULL, 0) = -1 ENODATA (No data available)
...
<I can see a lot more calls including calls to stat multiple times but I have cut it short. >
...
```

As you can see after the `statx` call, the next call is different. If this is indeed a problem with the seccomp profile not whitelisting `statx`, is there a way to find out what syscalls are whitelisted by running any specific command on the docker host or the container? I do not have any custom seccomp profiles files so I'm using the default profile.